# FileSystemWatcher or ASP.NET Cache for multiple files

Tags: asp.net, caching, filesystemwatcher

I'm working on an open source where I need to populate a dictionary from reading values from multiple xml files and whenever any of the xml file changes I have to update the dictionary. Since there are multiple files I thought of using `FileSystemWatcher`. Is this a good idea? or I've to go with ASP.NET cache with file dependency? I'm not sure how ASP.NET cache helps me in the case of multiple files.

Note: I've implemented a locking mechainsm while updating the dictionary so threading won't be an issue in the case of updating dictionary.

Comment: `FileSystemWatcher` is not easy to work with. Whenever I've tried to use it I've ended up using a timer to scan the directory for updated files instead. That is much more reliable.

Comment: @MartinLiversage Do you have idea how I can use ASP.NET cache with dependency on multiple files?

Comment: I think I've to use AggregateCacheDependency http://codeidol.com/csharp/csharpckbk2/Web/Caching-Data-with-Multiple-Dependencies/

Comment: No, not really, that is why I only wrote a comment because I can't provide an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating dependencies for multiple files you can use the [AggregateCacheDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.aggregatecachedependency.aspx) like this:

```
CacheDependency[] depArray = new CacheDependency () 
{
  new CacheDependency(Server.MapPath("foo.txt")),
  new CacheDependency(Server.MapPath("bar.txt"))
};

AggregateCacheDependency aggDep = new AggregateCacheDependency();
aggDep.Add(depArray);

Cache.Insert("key", value, aggDep);
```

Comment: On Cache.Insert there are two overloads for Item update and delete callback http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.insert.aspx